What event to listen for when a user clicks submit button in html5 invalid form?
I have a html5 form with html5 a required field. I want to catch the user interaction if the user submits the incomplete form and they are shown the the error message.
I thought I could use the invalid event, yet apparently it does not work.
How can I catch the invalid user interaction?
E.g.:


console.log('register event handler');

oninvalid = (event) => {
  console.log('it happened', event); // is not reached
};

addEventListener("invalid", (event) => {
  console.log('hallo'); // is not reached either
});
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Normal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required />
    <label>Required</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>




Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300256/how-do-i-detect-an-attempted-submission-of-invalid-html-forms

add oninvalid="alert('You must fill out the field!') on the element

@SudiptoBhattacharya I don't want to set it in each element. I want a global javascript handler.

Try this => document.addEventListener('invalid', function(e){
console.log('hallo');
}, true);

Due to the provided answer and the use case to listen for the invalid event, this is not a duplicate, albeit very much releated to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300256/how-do-i-detect-an-attempted-submission-of-invalid-html-forms

Inversed use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7946714/457268

You need to set the useCapture argument of addEventListener() to true for it to be fired on the element the listener it was assigned to, as the invalid event does not bubble.


document.addEventListener("invalid", () => {
  console.log('hallo');
}, true);
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Normal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" required />
    <label>Required</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>



More information on useCapture and the event phases is available in this SO answer.

I really appreciated the link to the other answer explaining the difference between capturing and bubbeling. My intuition in regards to event has been off for years, and I pretty much stumble again and again over the fact that many events won't bubble. The provided context in that linked answer really made the differences click for me.
